# Cannot import Oracle Client in ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core

With the new dotnet core, we can no longer import our referenced dlls externally, and instead have to get through a Nuget feed. I am trying to get `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` Nuget package to work with my project, but no luck so far.

Here's the error in my `project.json` file:

[image]

Says `The dependency Oracle.ManagedDataAccess >= 12.1.24160419 could not be resolved.`

This is the error from Package Manager output:

```
Project Oracle.ManagedDataAccess is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Project Oracle.ManagedDataAccess supports: net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
```

Does this mean I can no longer use this package? From what I've read so far, dotnet core does not support .net framework v4.5.1. If that is indeed the case, what are some alternatives I can use to connect to Oracle database?

Comment: Can you please share the full `project.json` file?

Comment: Your project needs to target net451 or newer and not netcorapp1.0 because Oracle.ManagedDataAccess is not compatible with CoreClr

Comment: @Pawel I know that. But the application targets netcoreapp1.0. If it was net451 I wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Why can't you change the target? Clearly this application cannot use netcoreapp1.0 if you have to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Comment: @Pawel Because its a web application? If you think that Oracle.ManagedDataAccess cannot be imported and there is no other alternatives just post an answer.

Comment: web applications can run on full .NET just fine. I just looked at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. It won't run on CoreClr. First, it has a dll that targets only net40 so it can use some APIs not available in CoreClr. Second it has native binaries in bin\x64 and bin\x86 subfolders. I think even if you forced this package into a netcoreapp1.0 CoreClr will not find these native dlls and things won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package and I don't think it can run on CoreClr. First, it has a dll that targets only net40 so it is likely it uses some APIs not available in CoreClr/CoreFx or relies on things being in the box/GAC. Second, it has native binaries in bin\x64 and bin\x86 subfolders. I think even if you forced this package into a netcoreapp1.0 it may not work. If they use `DllImport` attribute to import these dlls CoreClr will not be able to find them because the structure of a package containing native assets is a bit different in the new world. In my opinion because of this dependency your application should just target full .NET (e.g. net451 or newer).